# How do install extra drivers for Database Note Taker

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-redshift

I'd like to connect Database Note Taker to Redshift, but the standard drivers dont do it. What do I have to do in order to connect?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Database Note Taker FAQ](https://databasenotetaker.com/database-documentation/database-documentation-frequent-questions.aspx):

> **Can Database Note Taker connect to other database platforms?**
> Yes and we will add support for other platforms in the future. So long as it's a relational database and there are freely available connectors, then Database Note Taker will be able to work with it. Out of the box you can connect to **Microsoft Sql Server**, and **MySql** via ODBC.

Given that Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, it is highly unlikely that [Database Note Taker](https://databasenotetaker.com/) will work with Amazon Redshift.

I also note that the the website is dated 2014 and the program was last updated in 2016.

I also notice that there is a 'Contact Us' page on that website, so you should probably ask them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try the contact mail but I haven't had a response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try the contact mail but I haven't had a response.